# Template recursion differentiating between datatypes in a boot::tuple

Tags: c++, templates, boost, boost-fusion

Problem: I need a functional object of `A` to recurse for data types of boost::tuple but do something else for all other data types of the incoming member `t`.

```
class A{
public:
    template<typename T>
    void operator()(T& t) const{
//      if (t == tuple){
//          recurse
//      } else{
//          doSomething
//      }
    }
};

class B{
    void init(){
        boost::tuple<int, float> a;
        boost::tuple< boost::tuple<int, std::string>, float > b;

        boost::fusion::for_each(a, A());
        boost::fusion::for_each(b, A());
    }
};
```

What I tried was setting up static functions for all possible incoming data types above the declaration of `A` but than I was not able to get back into the recursive function, because those statics did not know `class A`.
My second approach was to implement static functions for all possible data types returning `true` for boost::tuple and `false` for any other (pretty much like in the example). But than I couldn't implement a `for_each` call, because (even though it was wrapped by the if case) my IDE says there was no matching function call (which is true for types of `int`, `float` and `string`).

Comment: I need a solution that works with LLVM 4.2 and GCC 4.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you could just provide two overloads of the call operator, one which accepts instantiations of `boost::tuple` and would call `boost::fusion::for_each()` on that tuple, and another fallback one that would accept any kind of argument, and perform concrete operations on "leaf" types:

```
class A
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    void operator()(T& t) const
    {
        // Do something
    }

    template<typename... Ts>
    void operator ()(boost::tuple<Ts...>& t) const
    {
        // Recurse
        boost::fusion::for_each(t, A());
    }
};
```

In the above example I am using C++11's variadic templates, so you will need a C++11-compliant compiler for that to work (and don't forget to specify the flag `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++0x` in the command line).

Comment: thank you very much. I'll read up on variadic templates and try to understand the syntax of `...`

Comment: Given that `boost::tuple` may be implemented as a pile of n-ary `template`s, why does `boost::tuple<Ts...>` work?  I'm guessing some clever language in the standard?

Comment: @Yakk: Thank you for noticing. In fact, in my answer I mixed `boost::tuple` and `std::tuple`. I don't know how `boost::tuple` is implemented, I (perhaps naively?) thought it would be implemented in a way that would make such variadic template patterns work